# Chart.js - Navigate through elements/tooltips using arrow keys

Tags: navigation, chart.js, accessibility

This is probably one of the more useful (AND SIMPLE) features missing from Chart.js. My code should mostly work already - if you don't have multiple labels/datasets - which is what I'm trying to figure out. We just need to iron out the last few details, and we'll have an awesome new feature.

For context, I'm using a line chart, and I'm on version 3.5.1 of Chart.js, but this should also work for the newest version (4.2.1 as of Feb 2023)

We can use `myChart.getActiveElements();` to get the currently selected element.

And we can use this, for example, to programmatically show a tooltip...
`myChart.tooltip.setActiveElements([{ datasetIndex: 1, index: 1 }]);`
`myChart.update();`

So it really shouldn't be that difficult to navigate through the chart.

Here's the code that I'm tinkering with.

```
const myChart = Chart.getChart("myChart"); // make sure to replace the "myChart"
var active_element;

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
 active_element = myChart.getActiveElements();
  if ( ! active_element.length ) { 
    myChart.setActiveElements([{ datasetIndex: 0, index: 0 }]);
    myChart.tooltip.setActiveElements([{ datasetIndex: 0, index: 0 }]);
    myChart.update();
    active_element = myChart.getActiveElements();
  }

  const active = active_element[0];
  const dataset = myChart.data.datasets[active.datasetIndex];
  const data = dataset.data;
  let index = active.index;
  if ( event.code === 'ArrowLeft' ) {
    index = index > 0 ? index - 1 : data.length - 1;
  } else if ( event.code === 'ArrowRight' ) {
    index = index < data.length - 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
  }
  console.log('active', active.datasetIndex);
  console.log('index ', index);
  myChart.setActiveElements([{ datasetIndex: active.datasetIndex, index }]);
  myChart.tooltip.setActiveElements([{ datasetIndex: active.datasetIndex, index }]);
  myChart.update();

});
```

**The main issue that I'm having trouble with, is when you have more than one label for each x-axis point (multiple datasets).**

Another obstacle that we'll need to overcome is when you have your mouse on the chart, you will always have the same active chartElement... Currently, having your mouse on the chart stops it from working. So instead we don't allow that, and we simply trigger the 0th element from the start, store the value, and use that value for future updates. This is fine for now, but ultimately should be solved.

This is a pretty fundamental accessibility feature that I think we're all surprised isn't available by default. People have been asking for it since at least 2016 as you can see here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1976

I'm so close to having a working solution. This code should run on any line chart, you just need to edit the first line of code `const myChart = Chart.getChart("your_chart_here");`

Let's do this!!

Comment: It’s great that you want to find a solution to this issue. But patching Chart.js from the outside is fragile, slow, and will only help a few. What is keeping you from fixing this in Chart.js itself? It’s Open Source, you could create a pull request. Apparently there is interest since 2016, so you’ll even have a lot of testers and maybe even programming help.

Comment: Are you able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Also, since my solution already almost works, I think it makes sense to see it to the end. Perhaps that will be enough to inspire the next person to patch it from the inside.

Comment: It’s a great start. Maybe you could share a link in the issue then. Otherwise here’s an introduction: [How to Contribute to Open Source](https://opensource.guide/how-to-contribute/)

Comment: I think the reason for Steve's "patch from the outside" approach is the Chart.js design philosophy (mentioned in the github issue) about not manipulating the DOM. In my opinion, this design philosophy collides with best practices for accessibility, so Chart.js are in a double bind - they either become obsolete in the era of mandatory WCAG conformance or they change their design philosophy. Why? Because the only way to communicate with assistive tech is via the DOM. (At least until AOM is finalised).

Comment: How are you hooking up the labels? If you use `aria-labelledby` you can point to more than one label, and they will be concatenated.

Comment: Remember that each element that gets focus should have a non-generic role, otherwise the label is likely to be ignored by assistive tech. If it's not a table/grid of cells, or a list, I would suggest using the `graphics-object` role for datapoint elements, if you can find nothing better. See  https://www.w3.org/TR/graphics-aria-1.0/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library, [Chart2Music](https://chart2music.com/docs/), that helps provide keyboard navigation and sonification for keyboard-only and screen reader users.

Since I love using chart.js, I also built a chart.js plugin for it. It's called [chartjs-plugin-chart2music](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-chart2music), and is still in beta.

You can get the accessibility support simply by registering the plugin.

```
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
import chartjs2music from "chartjs-plugin-chart2music";

// Register the plugin globally
Chart.register(chartjs2music);
```

If you want to play with it, here's a codepen example with keyboard navigation and sonification:
https://codepen.io/chart2music/full/YzaVxPK